# Change event firing more than once

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

I have a list of users that is populated with a Coldfusion cfloop from a query. Each user row has a button that can be clicked which invokes a modal. In that modal is a list of permissions that can be toggled on and off. I am using CSS3 flip switch checkboxes for the toggles. The values are populated from an ajax call.

**The problem**

When the user clicks the user row button to invoke the modal and fire off the ajax call all works well. The user can flip the switches which fires off ajax calls updated each permission. When the user clicks another user row, the modal is invoked and fires off another ajax call just fine. When the user flips a switch, it fires off 2 ajax calls instead of one. This is problem number one. Here is the code.

**JQUERY**

```
// PERMISSIONS MODAL
        $(function() {
        $('.tbody_permissions').on('click', 'button[class*=permissions_]', function () {
                var permissions_id      = $(this).attr("id");
                $.getJSON({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "cfc/cfc_Permissions.cfc?method=func_get_person_permissions&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        person_id:      permissions_id,
                        contract_id:    '<cfoutput>#permissions_contract#</cfoutput>',
                        project_id:     '<cfoutput>#permissions_project#</cfoutput>',
                        company_id:     '<cfoutput>#permissions_company#</cfoutput>',
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success:function(data_req) {
                        if(data_req && data_req.length) {   // DO SOMETHING
                            $.each(data_req, function(i, val) {
                                var message_type_req            = data_req[i].message_type;
                                var user_id_req                 = data_req[i].user_id;
                                var firstname_req               = data_req[i].firstname;
                                var lastname_req                = data_req[i].lastname;
                                var image_req                   = data_req[i].image;
                                var permission_req              = data_req[i].permission;
                                var purchasing_req              = data_req[i].purchasing;
                                var timekeeping_req             = data_req[i].timekeeping;

                                // *** SUCCESS ***
                                if(message_type_req == "SUCCESS" ||  message_type_req == "NONE") {   // DO SOMETHING
                                    $('#permission_user_id_modal').val(user_id_req);
                                    $('#permission_name').replaceWith("<h6 class='modal-title' id='permission_name'>" + firstname_req + ' ' + lastname_req + "</h6>");
                                    $('#permission_image').replaceWith("<div id='permission_image'><img src='" + image_req + "'></div>");
                                        if (permission_req == 1){
                                            $('#permission').attr('checked', 'checked');
                                            $('#permission').val(1);

                                        } else {
                                            $('#permission').removeAttr('checked');
                                            $('#permission').val(0);
                                        };
                                        if (purchasing_req == 1){
                                            $('#purchasing').attr('checked', 'checked');
                                            $('#purchasing').val(1);
                                        }else{
                                            $('#purchasing').removeAttr('checked');
                                            $('#purchasing').val(0);
                                        };
                                        if (timekeeping_req == 1){
                                            $('#timekeeping').attr('checked', 'checked');
                                            $('#timekeeping').val(1);
                                        }else{
                                            $('#timekeeping').removeAttr('checked');
                                            $('#timekeeping').val(0);
                                        };
                                    // Submit switch form data 
                                    $('#permission_modal').on('change', ':checkbox',function() {
                                        var switched_id             =   $(this).attr("id");
                                        var switched                =   $('#' + switched_id).val();
                                            if (switched    == 1){
                                                $('#' + switched_id).val(0);
                                                //console.log("switched_id: #" + switched_id);
                                                //console.log("switched off: " + switched);

                                                if (switched_id == 'permission'){
                                                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                                                        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                                                            $(this).trigger('click');
                                                            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                                                        }
                                                    });


                                                }
                                            }else{
                                                $('#' + switched_id).val(1);
                                                //console.log("switched_id: #" + switched_id);
                                                //console.log("switched on: " + switched);
                                            };
                                        var update_user             =   $('#permission_user_id_modal').val();
                                        var contract_id_update      =   "<cfoutput>#permissions_contract#</cfoutput>";
                                        var project_id_update       =   "<cfoutput>#permissions_project#</cfoutput>";
                                        var company         =   "<cfoutput>#permissions_company#</cfoutput>";
                                        var permission      =   $('#permission').val();
                                        var purchasing      =   $('#purchasing').val();
                                        var timekeeping     =   $('#timekeeping').val();
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "cfc/cfc_Permissions.cfc?method=update_person_permissions&returnformat=json",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            data: {
                                                contract_id:        contract_id_update,
                                                project_id:         project_id_update,
                                                person_id:          update_user,
                                                company:            company,
                                                permission:         permission,
                                                purchasing:         purchasing,
                                                timekeeping:        timekeeping
                                            },
                                            cache: false,
                                            success:function(data_update) {
                                                if(data_update && data_update.length) {   // DO SOMETHING
                                                    $.each(data_update, function(i, val) {
                                                    // SUCCESS
                                                        if(data_update[i].message_type == "SUCCESS") {   // DO SOMETHING
                                                            /*
                                                            var message_type                = data_update[i].message_type;
                                                            var permission_res              = data_update[i].permission;
                                                            var purchasing_res              = data_update[i].purchasing;
                                                            var timekeeping_res             = data_update[i].timekeeping;
                                                            */
                                                            // *** FAIL ***
                                                        } else if(data_update[i].message_type == "FAIL"){ // DO SOMETHING
                                                            html += "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Ooops:</strong> <em>" + message + "</em></div>";
                                                            $('.messagenote_settings').html(html);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return false;
                                    });
                                // *** FAIL ***
                                } else { // DO SOMETHING
                                    $('#error').val(messagenote);   
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**HTML**
*Example of 1 checkbox flip switch*

```
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="switch">
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox purchasing" id="purchasing" value="1" checked="checked">
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="purchasing">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
       purchasing
    </td>
    <td>
    <p class="small">
        access to purchasing
    </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Solution to the binding issue**

So if I understand the problem, I have added .off() to unbind the change event. This is what I did. I replaced

```
$('#permission_modal').on('change', ':checkbox',function() {
```

with

```
$('#permission_modal').off('change', ':checkbox').on('change', ':checkbox',function() {
```

That worked well but I think it may have caused another issue. Now there is only one update call being fired off BUT the CSS3 switch that was toggled does not update when another user row is invoked. It is as if has been unbound without the ability to be bound again. It is strange because the toggles are pure CSS3 so I can only think that it is the element has disappeared from the DOM. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I just can't reproduce the issue since most of the markup is generated by an unreachable JSON... But What I can say is `:checkbox` is not a valid selector. Maybe you want `[type='checkbox']` ?

Comment: yea.... it is a really tied in application that I can't give access to the api. I used :checkbox in order limit the code length. I am only showing 3 permissions for brevity in this example. There are like 15. So you are thinking I need to get rid of that abbreviated code....hmm. I will give that a try unless another solution is offered. Thank you Louys.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with *«abbreviated»*, but `:checked` and `:disabled` are valid selectors... But look at element's boolean properties. Not element's type. `:checkbox` simply do not exist.

Comment: I did not want to detail out each id or class for each permission being that they were so many. I didn't see your [type='checkbox'] recommendation for some reason. Let me try that instead of :checkbox.

Comment: I changed it to $('#permission_modal').off('change', '[type="checkbox"]').on('change', '[type="checkbox"]',function() { and am still experiencing the same issue. The jquery is not throwing an error and the calls are all working. It is just not changing the css3 flipswitch once the first update call is done.

Comment: Where is that `#permission_modal` in the markup? Try `$(document).on('change', '#permission_modal *[type="checkbox"]',function() {` --- And forget about the `.off()`, using delegation, you should not have the need to unbind if you delegate from a STATIC element.

Comment: #permission_modal is the id of the modal. I am using that as a focus and then the on change event is triggered on when the check box is changed.

Comment: So I changed to this.... 

$('#permission_modal').on('change', '#purchasing',function() {

and am still having the issue. The more I think of it... I do not think it is a binding issue. But this does still create multiple calls as I originally explained.

Comment: I'm not sure to get it... But I have to ask «Is #purchasing unique»? If you have the same `id` multiple times in the document. That is the problem.

Comment: It is unique. All of the ajax calls are working as designed. All the responses and the database updates are working. For some reason when the response comes back on the second getJSON call the 

 $('#purchasing').removeAttr('checked');

AND 

$('#purchasing').val(0);

works BUT the css3 does not change. It maintains the "checked" status from the previous updated that was performed. It is very strange. I'd hate to abandon the CSS3 and try something else.

Comment: It is like the checkbox value is 0 BUT the check box is checked.

Comment: ok... About checkboxes... If that is the question after all... `$('#permission').removeAttr('checked');` is a fail. The attribute is there only to provide the value to DOM on load. After that, you have to change the property : `$('#permission').prop('checked',false);` will work.

Comment: I have changed all as your recommend. Still the same issue. Very frustrating. It is as after I update the checkbox after the first request, the check boxes appear the same as the previous item updated BUT the checkbox values are correct. In other words... the source codes shows value="1" and checked="checked" and the checkbx is not checked visually....

Comment: So a little more info. If I just click the button for each user row to invoke the modal and do not update any of the checkboxes... after about 3 requests... the checkboxes stop changing based on response data. For instance the response data for "purchasing" will show "1" but the check box will be unchecked. It is unchecked because the last request was unchecked.

Comment: Did you change `$('#purchasing').attr('checked', 'checked');` for `$('#purchasing').prop('checked', true);`? -- That is the same logic... To change the checked state, you have to change the **property".

Comment: That is it! That fixed it. If you want to create the answer I will check it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes can have a `checked` attribute in the HTML markup.

That ONLY is to pass the `true` value to the `checked` PROPERTY of the element, which is a boolean.

So all markup showing `checked="checked"` is quite wrong since the value expected is a boolean.

It it does not really matter, since if the attribute is present whatever the string value attempted to be passed, the property will be `true`. If it is absent, it will be `false`.

In short, the real correct markup for a checked checkbox is:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

**Now**, that was about the HTML markup for on load property setting.
Afterward, the attribute is useless to change, since the markup has already been parsed. You have to change the property.

That is done like this:

```
// Check:
$(element).prop("checked",true);

// Uncheck:
$(element).prop("checked",false);
```

Or in vanilla JS:

```
// Check:
element.checked = true;

// Uncheck:
element.checked = false;
```